# Virtual inheritance in C++ usages/tricks

Tags: c++, oop

I've never used it in the professional software even though in our shop, and others I have worked for, we design large scale systems. The only time I messed with virtual inheritance was during my interview in a company. Nonetheless, I played with it during afterhours.

Do you guys use it? Do you understand how it works in depth (how most popular compiler vendors implement it)?  I would really like to know how it is used in professional software, if at all.  Tricks and tips would be appreciated, too.

To me, virtual inheritance was just a solution to an infamous diamond problem.  Hence, it never found its way in our software, as we don't have in our architecture MI resulting in the diamond.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main point with virtual inheritance is to prevent derived classes from inheriting multiple copies of different superior  classes.  This can occur in any case where there may be multiple inheritance -- as you correctly note, the "diamond problem", which is to say where the inheritance graph is a DAG instead of a strict tree.

The [C++ FAQ goes into it in some detail](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html).  I'd also recommend the C++ FAQ Book; I used to work for the authors and they're quite good.

Comment: +1 for the book and the site, I have the one & frequent the other :-)   Smart people who can explain things well... the 2 often don't go together.

Answer (score 5):

> I've never used it in the professional software even though in our shop,

Do you use `iostream`? We do. Look up the design of iostreams and you'll know you've been using virtual inheritance.

Comment: HAHAH, yeah indirectly we do use it :)

Answer (score 4):

Virtual inheritance can also be used to make a class a final class, i.e. to make it so that no other classes can derive from it. I grabbed that trick once from Stroustroup (<strike>http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation</strike> see below for updated hyperlinks and sources):

> The other variant of this problem, how to prevent derivation for logical reasons, has a solution in C++11. For example:
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```
>
> For older compilers, you can use a somewhat clumsy technique:
>         class Usable;
>
> ```
>   class Usable_lock {
>       friend class Usable;
>   private:
>       Usable_lock() {}
>       Usable_lock(const Usable_lock&) {}
>   };
>
> class Usable : public virtual Usable_lock {
>     // ...
> public:
>     Usable();
>     Usable(char*);
>     // ...
> };
>
> Usable a;
> class DD : public Usable { };
>
> DD dd;  // error: DD::DD() cannot access
>         // Usable_lock::Usable_lock(): private  member
> ```

---

### Update 2018

C++ has received a `final` keyword [in the meanwhile](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#final):

> ### Why doesn't C++ have a final keyword?
>
> [It has, but it is not as useful as you might think.](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation)

which leads to:

> ### Can I stop people deriving from my class?
>
> Yes, but why do you want to? There are two common answers:
>
> - for efficiency: to avoid my function calls being virtual
> - for safety: to ensure that my class is not used as a base class (for example, 
>     to be sure that I can copy objects without fear of slicing)
>
> In my experience, the efficiency reason is usually misplaced fear. In C++, virtual function calls are so fast that their real-world use for a class designed with virtual functions does not to produce measurable run-time overheads compared to alternative solutions using ordinary function calls. Note that the virtual function call mechanism is typically used only when calling through a pointer or a reference. When calling a function directly for a named object, the virtual function class overhead is easily optimized away.
>
> If there is a genuine need for "capping" a class hierarchy to avoid virtual function calls, one might ask why those functions are virtual in the first place. I have seen examples where performance-critical functions had been made virtual for no good reason, just because "that's the way we usually do it".
>
> The other variant of this problem, how to prevent derivation for logical reasons, has a solution in C++11. For example:
>
> ```
>   struct Base {
>       virtual void f();
>   };
>
>   struct Derived final : Base {   // now Derived is final; you cannot derive from it
>       void f() override;
>   };
>
>   struct DD: Derived {// error: Derived is final
>
>       // ...
>   };
> ```

... which then leads to the initial passage of this answer.

Comment: Link is dead (which is why one shouldn't post link-only answers).

Comment: @HenriMenke: And you are absolutely correct with that. To my defense, 9 years ago, this site was pretty much more wild west than today.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd want to use it if your architecture doesn't use multiple inheritance.

If you did happen to use MI I can't see why you *wouldn't* use virtual inheritance.  There doesn't seem to be any drawback except for remembering to add the virutal keyword in the right places.

Comment: Here's two reasons: 1) virtual inheritance requires subclasses to be aware (and if you refactor virtual bases, it impacts all of your users needlessly).  2) virtual inheritance adds runtime cost to every constructor and destructor.  Why pay that cost when it's almost never necessary?

Comment: Can you explain how refactoring virtual bases is different than refactoring normal bases in a diamond-inheritance situation?

For the constructor cost, isn't it quicker because when using a non-virtual base class it needs to make multiple copies of the base whereas with virtual it's just pointers?

Comment: Another disadvantage of virtual inheritance is that you can no longer downcast from pointer-to-Base to pointer-to-Derived with static_cast<Derived*>.  See this illuminating post for details: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/631ac4837db0abbb

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with several commercial libraries that required its use. For example, the library that Reuters supplied to access real-time financial market data used to require you to derive your listening classes from several base classes (don't know if it still does) and this needed virtual inheritance. It was no big deal, once you realised you had to use it - a fact not totally well documented.

Answer (score 0):

for gaining further insights regarding virtual inheritance you could also check out this post: http://cpptalk.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/constructor-selection-with-virtual-inheritance/
I have in-depth knoweldge of the mechanism, so if you have a specific question - just go ahead and ask.