# Motivation for not using virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I hope this question is not too vague, but coming from java, I can not think of any reason why I would use non-virtual functions in C++. 
Is there a nice example which demonstrates the benefit of non-virtual functions in C++.

Comment: Do you mean non-virtual methods or non-virtual inheritance?

Comment: Virtual inheritance is only ever useful in multiple inheritance scenarios. You should try to avoid those to begin with.

Comment: If you are referring to [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) then read about its disadvantages [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/656731/66516)

Comment: @melpomene sorry for being so unspecific, I meant virtual functions

Comment: Virtual functions are dangerous, somebody that derives your class can break your code by overriding the function and, say, not call the base function when they should.  In Java you have the *final* keyword, that's not available in C++.  Don't declare functions virtual unless you *expect* the function to be overridden.

Comment: @user - If having everything virtual in Java is good, why do we have the `final` keyword there. Seems pretty useless...

Comment: @HansPassant `final` is now also available in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of the linked question... This question is about virtual functions, not virtual inheritance.

Comment: I suggest this question should be reopened.  I like to add a new answer (that doesn't have to do with "cost").

Comment: @NikosC.- I believe this question was incorrectly marked as duplicate.  And I'd like to add a new answer.  How doI get this question reopened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual functions have a runtime cost associated with them. They are dispatched at runtime and thus are slower to call. They are similar to calling regular functions through a function pointer, where the address is determined at runtime according to the actual type of the object. This incurs overhead.

One of the C++ design decisions has always been that you should not pay for things you don't need. In contrast, Java does not concern itself much with this kind of low-level optimization.

Comment: The runtime cost is minimal compared to the trouble of defining the exact interface of *every* single member function that a derived class can override.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the principles on which C++ language is based is that you should not pay for something you don't use.

Virtual function call is more expensive than non-virtual function call, since in a typical implementation it comes through two (or three) additional levels of indirection. A virtual call cannot be inlined, meaning that the expenses can grow even higher due to fact that we have to call a full-fledged function.

Adding virtual functions to an class makes it polymorphic, thus creating some invisible internal structures inside objects of that class. These structures incur additional household expenses and preclude low-level processing of class objects.

Finally, separating functions into virtual and non-virtual ones (i.e into overridable and non-overridable ones) is a matter of your design. It simply makes no sense whatsoever to unconditionally make all functions in our class overridable in the derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that calling a virtual function can be slower, but not nearly as slow as most C++ programmers think.

Modern CPUs have gotten pretty good at branch prediction.  If, every time you execute a particular call to a virtual function, you are actually calling the same implementation, the CPU will figure that out and start "guessing" (speculatively executing) the call before it even computes the address.  This can often hide the cost of the virtual call completely, making it exactly as fast as a non-virtual call.  (If you doubt this, try it for yourself on a current-generation processor.)

If you are not calling the same implementation, then you are actually relying on the virtual dispatch, so you could not directly replace it with a non-virtual function anyway.

The only common exception to this is inlined functions, where the compiler can perform constant propagation, CSE, etc. between the caller and callee.  Obviously it cannot do this if it does not know the destination of the call at compile time.

But as a rule of thumb, your instinct that you always want to use virtual functions is not all that bad.  The times when the performance difference is noticeable are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Very few member functions in the standard library are virtual.

Offhand I can only remember the destructor and `what` function of standard exceptions.

As of 2012 the only good reason to have a virtual member function is to support overriding of that member function in a derived class, i.e. a **customization point**, and that can often be achieved in other ways (e.g. parameterization, templating).

However, I can remember at one time, like 15 years ago, being very frustrated with the design of Microsoft's MFC class framework. I wanted every member function to be virtual so as to be able to override the functionality and in order to be able to more easily debug things, as an *alternative to non-existing or very low quality documentation*. Thus, I argued that virtual should be the default, also in other software.

I have since understood that MFC was not representative and is not representative of C++ software in general, so the MFC-specific reasons do not apply in general. :-)

---

The efficiency cost of virtual function is, like, virtually non-existent. :-) See for example the international standarization committee's [Technical Report on C++ Performance](http://www.stroustrup.com/performanceTR.pdf). However, there is a real cost in providing this freedom for derived classes, because freedom implies responsibility: any derived class then has to ensure that overriding the member function respects the contract of the base class.

Comment: another notable case (apart std::exception and derived) are `iostream` and `streambuf`. Both use virtual functions as "customization points".

Answer (score 0):

C++ is meant to be both fast like C, and support OO and generic programming (templates). To achieve both this goals, C++ member functions by default can't be inerited, unless you mark them as virtual, in which case the virtual table gets into business. So you can build classes that don't involve virtual functions, when not needed.

Although not as efficient as non-virtual calls, virtual functions calls using the virtual table are very fast. You might notice the different only within tight loops that do nothing but calling a member function. So the Java way - all members are "virtual" - is indeed more practical IMO.